# How to avoid holes in Chiffon cake?

Tags: eggs, cake, meringue, folding

I have recently baked a couple of chiffon cakes, overall I'm happy with the bake - the structure and flavor are very good. However I have a recurring issue with large holes in the sponge, see the picture below.

[image]

I suspect it is some of the meringue not being fully incorporated into the batter and that large blobs of meringue are causing these holes. I could see there were blobs of meringue, but I was concerned if I kept folding to incorporate them I would knock out air from the meringue so I left them. The meringue was pretty hard, and I found it tough going, the blobs just wouldn't break up.

Do I need to keep folding, or is there a way to break up these blobs? Or is my meringue too hard? If it's the meringue, how do I make it softer? Should I speed up pouring in the sugar and whip the whites less?

Comment: Personally I like it, from the look. Without the holes, it would look like a synthetic grocery cake. Yours look like a yummy home-made cake. What's the problem with the holes?

Comment: Unincorporated meringue looks like white patches that taste of meringue - it doesn't make holes. Holes are a result of large bubbles of evaporated water getting trapped.

Comment: @Galastel, that's interesting, what do you think I could do to avoid the holes?

Comment: @Jeffrey, the holes are just a bit too big, I don't mind a bit of unevenness but that's pushing it!

Comment: I'd try lowering the baking temperature (and extending baking time to compensate). Trouble is, I don't really remember *why*. (It's nearly 2am here, so my thinking capacity is not at its peak.)

Comment: Depends on what _was_ the baking temp? 325 F?

Comment: Did you cut through the batter in the pan with a knife before baking?

Comment: I didn't @DebbieM, I've never heard of that procedure.

Comment: I don't know about chiffon cake, but for other cakes, I'll slam the cake pan against the counter a couple of times ... supposedly it's to deal with this sort of problem.  (I've never compared side by side, so I have no idea what happens when I *don't* do it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to run a knife gently through the batter to pop any large air bubbles before baking. While not included in all chiffon/angle food cake recipes, directions to remove large air pockets by running a knife through the batter in the pan before baking is not that unusual.